# What is "dom.push.userAgentID" preference?

Tags: firefox, about-config

I have a modified `dom.push.userAgentID` preference, type is "string" (I won't share the value, may be unique), in about:config. I certainly haven't modified or created this manually, but an extension may have created the preference.

Answer (score 3):

Its the user agent used by `dom.push` (the WebSocket notification system introduced in Firefox 44) if `privacy.resistFingerprinting` is enabled (boolean `true`).

As for the "uniqueness" it seems to be just some random hex string.
Resetting the preference will regenerate another random hex almost immediately.